# Find a linear map with conditions for kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find a linear map T: M_2(R) -> R[t]_3 such that the kernel is the subspace of symmetric 2 x 2 matrices (a, b, b, c), a, b, c real numbers and the Image need to contain a polynomial of grade 3.

I tried to write (a, b,b,c ) = a + bt + btˆ2 + btˆ3 and write the kernel basis in function of a, but I think that wrong. I'm really lost in this exercise. How should I start?

Comment: Please format your mathematical expressions properly. [Here is a guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on mathematical formatting for this website

Comment: You say the kernel is the subspace of "asymmetric" $2 \times 2$ matrices. Do you instead mean that the kernel is the subspace of **symmetric** $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: I meant symmetric 2x2 matrices. Sorry, my bad. Will edit.

Comment: I will take time to learn how to format the expressions. I'm new here. Sorry about my bad post.

Comment: That's all right, sorry if I came off as particularly stern. Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try the linear transformation of the form
$$
T \pmatrix{a & b\\c & d} = (b - c) t^3.
$$
Verify that this transformation has a *kernel* consisting of the symmetric matrices and that its image contains a polynomial of degree $3$.

Comment: I suppose this doesn't apply for symmetric matrices, right?

Comment: @Brasilian_student I don't understand your question